# using rxjs debounceTime with react hooks

Tags: rxjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use rxjs `debounceTime` with react hooks.  This is the code I have so far

```
const searchFriendSubject = new Subject();
const subscription = searchFriendSubject.pipe(debounceTime(1500)).subscribe(val => {
  console.log('This is the value ', val);
});

const friendComponent = () => {
  const [formData, setSearchTerm] = useState({
    searchTerm: { value: '', valid: true }
  });

  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    const formDataToSet = {
      ...formData,
      ...{ searchTerm: { valid: true, value: newValue } }
    };
    setSearchTerm(formDataToSet);
    searchFriendSubject.next(newValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = searchFriendSubject.pipe(debounceTime(1500)).subscribe(val => {
      console.log('This is the value ', val);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  });

  return (
    <FriendSearchComponentStyles.containerBlock>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onChange}
      ></input>
    </FriendSearchComponentStyles.containerBlock>
  );
};
```

The problem is that the subscription does not fire at all.  If I remove `subscription.unsubscribe();` from the `effect` then the subscription works but fires many times.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and see.

Comment: Thanks this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the duplicate subscription wentjun mentions, your main problem is you have no dependency array on your effect, thus it unsubscribes/resubscribes *on every render*.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = searchFriendSubject.pipe(debounceTime(1500)).subscribe(val => {
    console.log('This is the value ', val);
  });

  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

pass an empty array if you only want to subscribe on mount and unsubscribe on unmount.  Or pass some prop values if you want to resubscribe when those props change.

Comment: I tried this as well still does not work.